Callable template type deduction questions
In the following C++ (MSVC C++20) code, the goal is to make sure that my templates can properly figure out the type of the first argument of a member function.
#include <tuple>

template <typename... Args>
struct args_holder
{
    using type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <typename T>
struct base_holder;

template <typename Class, typename Proto, typename... Args>
struct base_holder<Proto(Class::*)(Args...)> : args_holder<Args...>
{
};

template <typename T>
using first_arg_type = std::tuple_element_t<0, typename base_holder<T>::type>;

struct test_struct
{
    void test_function(int x)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<first_arg_type<decltype(test_struct::test_function)>, int>);
}

The compiler chokes on this code saying that 'type': is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'base_holder<void (int)>', but if I add a & before the test_struct::test_function, then everything works fine.
First question: What exactly does the & do? According to IntelliSense, either with or without the & the decltype evaluates to void(test_struct::*)(int x) and the template evaluates to type int.
Second question: I'm having trouble understanding the deduction flow from typename base_holder<T>::type. How does the specialization understand to choose the template with 2+ parameters along with splitting those types from the single decltype type given to it?

"What exactly does the & do?..." It gives you the member function pointer. It is necessary to use & here because member functions don't implicitly decay to pointers. In fact, pointer to member functions are not actually pointers.

Why there is no implicit conversions to pointers of member functions

Do you know what decltype(&test_struct::test_function) produces? It gives you a pointer to the member function. That is, void(test_struct::*)(int). So first_arg_type<decltype(test_struct::test_function)> becomes first_arg_type<void (test_struct::*)(int)>

that and decltype(test_struct::test_function) both seem to make void(test_struct::*)(int x)?

Yes, first_arg_type<decltype(test_struct::test_function)> becomes first_arg_type<void (test_struct::*)(int)>. So you're passing void(test_struct::*)(int) as the template argument to first_arg_type. This should make it clear. This is the reason you've Proto(Class::*)(Args...) in the base_holder. Refer to the second dupe What is this member pointer syntax?

Ok, so that looks like it means Proto, Class, Args... are being deduced automatically from the compiler even though it is given the single void (test_struct::*)(int) from the decltype? Also, you said the decltype becomes first_arg_type<void (test_struct::*)(int)>, which seems to be a member function pointer. So it is the same as the decltype(&...)?

Using & is necessary before test_struct::test_function because you can't get a pointer to member function without the &. In other words, test_struct::test_function will not work without the &. Second, yes deduction happens automatically when the argument test_struct::test_function is passed. I would also highly recommend a good c++ book before writing any real/advanced c++ program. C++ is one of the most complicated/difficult programming language to learn. It take years to learn it properly.
